# Combined report for multiple business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting

I've got a Salesforce instance that has a few dozen business units within it. Is there any way to generate some of the more basic reports (email sends, email sends by user) that would aggregate mailings from all business units, instead of having to manually go in to each business unit and generate a separate report for each one? Any help/advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Forgive the question, as I am not understanding the situation. Are you saying that you have multiple salesforce orgs, each with their own user listings, or are you saying that you have 1 salesforce org with multiple user names and security rules segregating them?

Comment: My fault, I could've explained that better. Little bit of a newb...it's actually for Salesforce Marketing Cloud. We've got the one org, but within it it's broken out into multiple business units. Users have accounts to the org, but are granted access to only the ones they're working in. You can toggle back/forth between BUs you've got access to. I'm an admin, w/ access to everything, and am looking to export a report to see how many emails are being sent from the org, across all BUs. Just wondering if there's an easier way to do that w/o having to export one from each individual BU.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I am not familiar with that type of setup. So, I am unable to help here.

Comment: No worries, I was actually able to figure this out (you can export a send summary to Excel from the primary business unit that'll have tabs for each BU underneath it in the hierarchy). Thanks anyway!